# [Python3]Reformatting JSON correctly

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I am scraping a website with Requests and BS4, and I pulled the following JSON (if you could call it that). The problem is it is not really formatted correctly:

```
{'event':'productClick', 'userId': null,
  'portalId': null,
  'cookieId': null,
  'customerId': null,
  'customerType': null,
  'sessionId': null,
  'displayMode': null,
  'userAgent': null,
  'language_Iso639_1Code': null,
  'userAgentIsMobile': null,
  'user': null,
  'ecommerce': {
    'click': {
      'actionField': {
        'list': 'Produktdetails Varianten',
        'id': null
      },
      'products': [
        {
          'id': '5714877',
          'name': 'G-Series G610 Orion Brown',
          'price': '139.0000',
          'brand': 'Logitech',
          'category': 'Tastatur',
          'variant': 'USB, CH, Kabel, MX-Brown',
          'gx_nameWithBrand': 'Logitech G-Series G610 Orion Brown',
          'gx_brandId': 292,
          'gx_productTypeId': 55,
          'gx_priceExcl': 'CHF 128.70',
          'gx_isSalesPromotion': false,
          'gx_isShownInShowRoom': false,
          'gx_rating': 4.5,
          'gx_productGroup1': 389,
          'gx_productGroup2': 254
        }
      ]
    }
  }}
```

Is there any way I can have the JSON formatted to JSON standards?

Comment: formatted for what

Comment: @depperm Formatted to RFC4627 JSON standard.

Comment: I'm sorry, aside from single quotes (which, by the way make this thing you pasted not a valid JSON), what exactly is wrong with it? And what type is the thing you pasted, a string? A dict?

Comment: @PavelGurkov The single quotes aren't a problem, but the values have no quotes and I do not know how to quote them. It is a string.

Comment: `null` and `false` (without quotes) are valid JSON, as are numbers without quotes

Comment: So @ou_snaaksie, could you please clarify what exactly the question is, and what result do you expect? In it's current form, to make the string comply with RFC 4627 all you have to do is to replace single quotes with double quotes.